# Enhancing linear image resolution in R with vectors

Tags: r, image-processing, ggplot2, resolution, ggmap

I am iterating a ggmap request with google over a list of cities. Using the styles argument, I remove all elements except for roads.

Please see the 1280x1280 image output below.

[image: City of Chengdu]

There is a limit on the resolution of the image (1280 x 1280) but I want to print the cities out in higher resolution (preferably 4k x 4k).

Given that the images are really just lines, is there a method to enhance the sharpness of them in R using, say, an array of directional vectors?

```
style <- c(c(feature = "administrative", visibility = "off"),
       c("&style=", feature = "all", element = "labels", visibility = "off"),
       c("&style=", feature = "road", color = "black"),
       c("&style=", feature = "landscape", color = "0xffffff"),
       c("&style=", feature = "water", color = "0xffffff"),
       c("&style=", feature = "poi", color = "0xffffff"),
       c("&style=", feature = "transit", color = "0xffffff"),
       c("&style=", feature = "transit.line", weight = "0"),
       c("&style=", feature = "transit.line", color = "black")
      )

ggmap(get_googlemap(center = "Chengdu", 
  zoom = 10, 
  source = "google", 
  maptype = "roadmap",
  #color = "bw",
  size = c(640, 640),
  format = "png8",
  messaging = FALSE,
  scale = 2,
  style = style),
  extent = "device")
```

Comment: Hi Grantham, welcome to SO. This is an interesting question, but it may not be on topic as you [ask for a package recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). (and someone has already voted to close it for this reason). I suppose you could edit to include a very small example code to produce one map figure, and discuss how to improve the resolution (without the explicit request for package that some don't like). If you are really only wanting a recommendation you could try  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you adjusted the zoom level in your `ggmap` call? Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: Thank you 20650, code added and request removed. Camille, I don't mean changing the zoom level, but the image resolution itself.

Comment: A workaround would be calculating the centerpoints of adjoining tiles, and downloading zoomed-in quadrants of the city (at the full resolution), then joining them together at the edges to produce your desired image. Other than that, check out the `magick` package for image manipulation.